# Display both negative and positive horizontal in a single bar chart

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot, bar-chart

[image: Without animation for negative values][image][image]I want to display horizontal bar chart... in it.. positive bar chart will animate from left to right and negative bar will animate from right to left..

i also attached my two different types of array...1 for positive and 1 for negative

When i run this code... negative bar value look like mirror effect...and for positive value, it use two color in each bar...

please help me to solve it..
if you can find anything wrong in code.. then please let me know

i attach two images also.. 1 for negative and 1 for positive

and ya, you can see that how values are display in negative bar...i also need to solve it also..

```
sampleArray:
<__NSArrayM 0xbae0940>(
{
    x = 0;
    y = "97.71425628662109";
},
{
    x = 0;
    y = "-70.55500793457031";
}
)


sampleArray:
<__NSArrayM 0x12a295a0>(
{
    x = 0;
    y = "97.71425628662109";
},
{
    x = 0;
    y = "450.6826171875";
}
)
```

Here is my whole code...

```
CPTGraphHostingView *hostingView = [[CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 100, 300, 300)];
hostingView.hostedGraph = self.barChart;
[self addSubview:hostingView];
    plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) self.barChart.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(-200.0f) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(650.0f)];
plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(00.0f) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(400.0f)];



- (void) animateNow
{


CPTBarPlot *barPlot = [CPTBarPlot tubularBarPlotWithColor:[CPTColor orangeColor] horizontalBars:YES];

// define the plot range -  between LTM and NEW, diffrence is 200
barPlot.plotRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(0.0) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(200)];//xAxisLength

// LTM will display at 100th point and NEW will display at 300th coz of 200 range
barPlot.barOffset = CPTDecimalFromFloat(100.00f);
barPlot.baseValue = CPTDecimalFromString(@"0");
barPlot.borderColor = [[UIColor clearColor]CGColor];
barPlot.lineStyle = nil;

// Width of the each bar
barPlot.barWidth = CPTDecimalFromFloat(30.0f);
barPlot.cornerRadius = 1.0f;
barPlot.dataSource = self;


// transform.scale.x for horizontal bar growth
CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale.x"];
if([[[self.sampleArray objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:Y_VAL]floatValue] < 0)
{
    anim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:-1.0];
    anim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
}
else
{
    anim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
    anim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];

}
[anim setDuration:2.0f];
anim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
anim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];

anim.removedOnCompletion = NO;
anim.delegate = self;
anim.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

barPlot.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
[barPlot addAnimation:anim forKey:@"grow"];
[self.barChart addPlot:barPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace ];


}


-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot
{
    /* if([plot.identifier isEqual:@"LTM"])
      return [self.sampleArray count]; */
        // return [self.sampleArray count];
    return [self.sampleArray count];
 }


-(CPTLayer *)dataLabelForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{

NSDictionary *bar;
CPTTextLayer *label;

if([plot.identifier isEqual:@"LTM"])
{
    bar = [self.sampleArray objectAtIndex:0];
    label = [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", [[bar valueForKey:Y_VAL]floatValue]]];
}
else if([plot.identifier isEqual:@"NEW"])
{
    bar = [self.sampleArray objectAtIndex:1];
    label = [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", [[bar valueForKey:Y_VAL]floatValue]]];    }
else
{
    return nil;
}

float dataLabelOffset;
if([[self.sampleArray objectAtIndex:index]valueForKey:Y_VAL]> 0)
{
    dataLabelOffset = -5.0f;

}
else
{
    dataLabelOffset = 10.0f;

}

plot.labelOffset = dataLabelOffset;
NSLog(@"Offset = %f",plot.labelOffset);
// label.textStyle = textStyle;
return label;
}

-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{

   NSDictionary *sample = [self.sampleArray objectAtIndex:index];

if (fieldEnum == CPTScatterPlotFieldX)
{
    return [sample valueForKey:X_VAL];
}
else
{

    return [sample valueForKey:Y_VAL];
}
}


-(CPTFill *)barFillForBarPlot:(CPTBarPlot *)barPlot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
     CPTColor *color = nil;

// Index = 0, for LTM and Index = 1 for NEW.

NSLog(@"%@",barPlot.identifier);

switch ( index )
{
    case 0:
        color = [CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:147.0/255.0 green:149.0/255.0 blue:152.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        break;

    case 1:
        color = [CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:255.0/255.0 green:160.0/255.0 blue:47.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        break;


    default:
        break;
}

CPTGradient *fillGradient = [CPTGradient gradientWithBeginningColor:color endingColor:color];

return [CPTFill fillWithGradient:fillGradient];

}
```

Comment: Does everything look ok if you don't use the animations?

Comment: sorry but that i didn't try.. coz first priority is to do animation...so cant remove animation from it.. i know there is some problem second bar plot but not able to find the exact one

Comment: Let's troubleshoot without animations first. Can you describe the problem with the second bar plot?

Comment: I used second bar plot for negative horizontal bar... coz it should be animated in wrong side.. and after added second bar plot, you can see the affect of it in the first image (2nd bar has two color), i think thats the problem of second bar plot.

Comment: Hello eric, i edited my question.. i added without animation effect on my chart.. negative values also display into right side..so can you please help in it.i commented add animation line..

Comment: hello eric, i think there is some mistake in plot range also.. i am not able figure it out..

Answer (score 1):

When setting up the plots, don't use the `plotRange` or `barOffset`. You'll get better drawing performance if you use a solid color fill instead of a gradient (your gradient had the same start and end colors).

```
- (void) animateNow
{
    CPTBarPlot *barPlot = [CPTBarPlot tubularBarPlotWithColor:[CPTColor orangeColor] horizontalBars:YES];
    barPlot.lineStyle = nil;
    barPlot.barWidth = CPTDecimalFromFloat(30.0f);
    barPlot.cornerRadius = 1.0f;
    barPlot.dataSource = self;

    CPTColor *color = [CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:147.0/255.0 green:149.0/255.0 blue:152.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    barPlot.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:color];

    CPTBarPlot *barPlot1 = [CPTBarPlot tubularBarPlotWithColor:[CPTColor blueColor] horizontalBars:YES];
    barPlot1.barWidth = CPTDecimalFromFloat(30.0f);
    barPlot1.lineStyle = nil;
    barPlot1.cornerRadius = 1.0f;
    barPlot1.dataSource = self;

    CPTColor *color1 = [CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:255.0/255.0 green:160.0/255.0 blue:47.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    barPlot1.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:color1];

    barPlot.identifier = @"LTM";
    [self.barChart addPlot:barPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace ];

    barPlot1.identifier = @"NEW";
    [self.barChart addPlot:barPlot1 toPlotSpace:plotSpace ];
}
```

With plots configured this way, the plot space setup is simpler:

```
plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) self.barChart.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(0.0) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(450.0)];
plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(-0.5) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(1.0)];
```

I'm assuming you want a single horizontal bar built using two plots to get the different colors. If so, here is how I would write the datasource methods:

```
// datasource
-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    NSDictionary *sample = nil;
    if([plot.identifier isEqual:@"LTM"])
    {
        sample = self.sampleArray[0];
    }
    else if([plot.identifier isEqual:@"NEW"])
    {
        sample = self.sampleArray[1];
    }

    switch (fieldEnum) {
    case CPTBarPlotFieldBarLocation:
        return @(index);
        break;
    case CPTBarPlotFieldBarTip:
        return sample[Y_VAL];
        break;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Note the plot field identifiers are bar plot location and tip rather than the scatter plot enum values. With a horizontal bar plot, the location values are along the y-axis and the tip and base are on the x-axis.

Comment: thanks a lot eric, and i also update my question.. i am able to do that negative horizontal bar.if anything wrong in my code, then please let me know

Comment: I think you're making this more complicated than it needs to be. Why are you using the `plotRange` and `barOffset`?

Comment: because without plotRange, i am not able to display negative bar from right to left and barOffset , i want to display my first bar at 100th position and next one at 300th...

Comment: The `plotRange` [property](http://core-plot.github.io/iOS/interface_c_p_t_bar_plot.html#a91e6813045c340ad81e62949c1f19b18) determines the bar spacing along the y-axis. If you know where you want the bars, don't set the `plotRange` or `barOffset` and just return the correct location for the `CPTBarPlotFieldBarLocation` field in the datasource.